# Joomla 3.2 custom auth without adding local user

Tags: php, authentication, joomla3.2

I'm currently working on a fairly large Joomla project which needs external User-Authentication (only Registered User-Group, so no administrators or publishers and so on need to be authenticated remotely), which connects to an external database which holds all users and passwords.

To accomplish this, I wrote a custom Joomla Authentication plugin, which works already.

Every time I authenticate a user via the plugin, Joomla automatically adds a local (joomla) user with the given data if it does not already exist.

My question:
Since there are a lot of users (10000+) and they area managed via the external db, is it possible to authenticate the users without having Joomla add a local user?

My plugin code:

```
public function onUserAuthenticate($credentials, $options, &$response)
{
        // custom method, do stuff, connect to the database, check if username and password are correct, get user row
        $result = $this->getExtUser($credentials);
        
        if(!empty($result))
        {
            $response->type = 'myauth';
            $response->email = $result['email'];
            $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
        else
        {
            $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
        }
}
```

Comment: maybe you could disable the standard authentication plugin? But even if it worked you would need a way to re-enable it in order to grant administrators access to the backend

Comment: Hmmm.. maybe that would be an idea, i will look into it, thanks!